# Removing duplicate data out of a store and binding it to a combobox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

Below is the pseudo code. After removing the duplicate data and binding it to another pre-defined combobox, the duplicated values still show up in the drop down list. Please advise. Thank you!

```
var k,state=[],repeat=[];
mystore.each(function(r){
         k=r.get('Action');
         if(state[k]) repeat.push(r);
         else state[k]=true;
});
mystore.remove(repeat); // sorry, forgot this line
my A_combobox=Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#A_combobox')[0];
A_combobox.bindStore(mystore);
```

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to show. You're not removing anything.

Comment: can you make your code little more clear.how this loop is for removing duplicates ?

Comment: Please add a fiddle with your code,

Comment: Updated the code. Please check again for me

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine for me as you can see in this fiddle - [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fq9).

Check that your field name is correct in this line `k=r.get('Action');` and that you actually do have duplicates in the data.

If you could provide more details for preferably a fiddle containing your code to replicate the issue I will update the answer with more information. Without that I cannot see any issues with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I added below code in the definition of combobox and it works now. Wondering why

queryModel: "local",